# How do I build juju-core from source?

Tags: compiling, juju

I'm interested in compiling and running juju-core from source. How can I do this? What are the risks involved?

Answer (score 4):

Before going in to this, according to the README in juju-core:

> Note that the use of --upload-tools forces the instances to run with the same
>   series and architecture of your development system.  Currently the only
>   supported architecture that can be deployed is amd64, so you must develop on
>   64-bit machines.

If you do not have an amd64 machine, or are trying to compile for i386, ARM, etc these steps will likely not work.

## Setup Dependencies

The following packages are required to build juju-core:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential bzr zip git-core mercurial golang-go
```

The `golang-go` package will prompt you about anonymous usage statistics and if you wish to opt-in. Select Yes or No depending on your interest.

After installation you'll need to create a `GOPATH`, which is what go will use for downloading and compiling dependencies. You can set this to any directory you choose, for example `~/go`. You can read more about gopath with `go help gopath`

```
export GOPATH=${HOME}/go
mkdir -p $GOPATH
```

Then prefix or append `GOPATH` to your `PATH`. It's recommended you prefix your `PATH` as it'll give you your compiled version by default. You'll still be able to access other installed versions of Juju, though you'll have to use an absolute path to access them. If you do not wish to have `GOPATH` in your path, you can bypass this step.

```
PATH="$GOPATH/bin:$PATH"
```

## Building & Installing

Once your environment is setup, build juju-core is a relatively straight forward process. You'll first need to get the latest code for juju-core in a manner that go will know what to do with. Simply run the following command to fetch the latest source:

```
go get -v launchpad.net/juju-core/...
```

This will have go fetch juju-core and the source of all dependencies. Finally, to build juju-core run:

```
go install -v launchpad.net/juju-core/...
```

This should take a few seconds to complete. Once finished you can verify juju compiled properly by running `which juju` if you prefixed your `PATH` with `GOPATH`. If not you can verify it's installed with `$GOPATH/bin/juju version` which should report the current compiled version of juju-core.

## Using

Once juju-core is built and you're able to use it as you like, there are a few caveats to be made aware of. First, whenever you run a bootstrap you'll need to include the `--upload-tools` flag, otherwise you'll end up having the 'released' version of the juju-core tools installed instead of the newly compiled ones.

```
juju bootstrap -e <your_environment> --upload-tools
```

Also, juju-core isn't compatible with previously deployed juju versions less than 0.7 (the python version of juju). You'll need to create new environments.yaml definitions and use different `control-bucket` keys. If you want to maintain two separate environment files you can do so by specifying a `JUJU_HOME` environment variable:

```
export JUJU_HOME=~/.juju-core
mkdir -p $JUJU_HOME
juju init -w
```

This will create a new boilerplate `environments.yaml` file in `~/.juju-core/` where you can maintain your juju-core environments separate from previous versions of juju.

## Removal

If you wish to remove the compiled version of juju-core you can do so at anytime by running `rm -rf $GOPATH`. This should return your system back to a state prior to when you had your compiled source version of juju-core.